# Change hr attributes on change elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I suppose that it must be simple to do that but I've no experience with javascript and it's getting difficult to me.
I've got an hr element on my page and both a color picker and a dropdownlist with different values from 1 to 10. 
What I need to do is change hr height and color when color picker or dropdownlist changes its values.

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="colourSelector" class="row">
<input id="backgroundcolor" name="backgroundcolor" size="6" maxlength="6" type="text" style="display: none;"><div class="colorPicker-picker" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">&nbsp;</div></div>

<div id="lineHeight" class="row">
<select name="lineHeight" id="lineHeight">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select></div>

<div id="divlineDemo" class="section row">
<hr id="lineDemo" style="height: 2px; background-color: red; border: 0;"> </div>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        var val= $("select#lineHeight").val();
        $("select#lineDemo").height().value; 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your Javascript code?

Comment: @JavierEslava: Use the "edit" link, not comments, to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of what you're trying to achieve.

You are setting `lineHeight` id 2 different times which caused me a headache to figure out. I renamed the ID of your select to `lineHeightSelect` and also changed the colorpicker to `type="color"`.

```js
    $(function() {
      var colorPicker = $('#backgroundcolor');
      var headline = $('#lineDemo');
      var lineHeight = $('#lineHeightSelect');
      
      lineHeight.on("change", function(){
        headline.css("height", $(this).val() + "px");
      });
      
      colorPicker.on("change", function() {
        headline.css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
      });
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colourSelector" class="row">
  <input id="backgroundcolor" name="backgroundcolor" size="6" maxlength="6" type="color" style="display: block;">

</div>

<div id="lineHeight" class="row">
  <select name="lineHeight" id="lineHeightSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="divlineDemo" class="section row">
  <hr id="lineDemo" style="height: 2px; background-color: red; border: 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks praszyk!!! It works!!! And now an additional question. I must to save selected values from lineDemo in a database field. How can I do that?

Comment: Use $.ajax inside one of the change events to submit the values to a server-side script where you save your newly changed variables into the database

Comment: No problem. If you have additional questions you should open a new question on stack overflow. (don't forget to search before you open a new question). Also consider `accepting` a solution listed in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#lineHeight').change(function () {
    var val = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $('#lineDemo').css('height', val+'px')
})
$('#backgroundcolor').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#lineDemo').css('background-color', val)
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjwvb9h2/2/)

I used the value of selected option as `height of the hr`

Comment: he doesn't need jQuery for this

Comment: @Saar: Providing a jQuery solution is a valid answer as the OP tagged the question with the jQuery tag.

Comment: I understand but you can see: "but I've no experience with javascript". n/m

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('#lineHeight').on('change',function(){ jQuery('#lineDemo').css('color','red').css('height','4px')
```

Comment: what about color picker?